# make ATIDAQ C Library

Tags: c++, c, makefile

For whatever reason after [download](http://www.ati-ia.com/library/software/daq_ft/ATIDAQ%20C%20Library.zip)ing the [ATIDAQ C Library](http://www.ati-ia.com/Products/ft/software/daq_software.aspx) I am not able to even make their stock examples. The file structure looks as such:

```
├── ATIDAQ
│   ├── ascii.h
│   ├── asciitab.h
│   ├── dom.c
│   ├── dom.h
│   ├── events.c
│   ├── expatls.c
│   ├── ftconfig.c
│   ├── ftconfig.h
│   ├── ftrt.c
│   ├── ftrt.h
│   ├── ftsharedrt.h
│   ├── iasciitab.h
│   ├── latin1tab.h
│   ├── nametab.h
│   ├── node.c
│   ├── stack.c
│   ├── stack.h
│   ├── utf8tab.h
│   ├── xmldef.h
│   ├── xmlparse.c
│   ├── xmlparse.h
│   ├── xmlrole.c
│   ├── xmlrole.h
│   ├── xmltok.c
│   ├── xmltok.h
│   ├── xmltok_impl.c
│   ├── xmltok_impl.h
│   └── xmltok_ns.c
├── readme.txt
└── Samples
    ├── calinfo.c
    ├── ftconvert.c
    └── makefile
```

### readme file mentions:

The following files should be compiled as part of your project: ftconfig.c ftrt.c dom.c expatls.c node.c stack.c xmlparse.c xmlrole.c xmltok.c

In addition to the above files, the files "events.c", "xmltok_impl.c", and 
"xmltok_ns.c" are also included in this library, but are not meant to be
directly compiled, as they are '#include'd into other library files.

None of these files are intended to be modified.

But there is a makefile already created which looks as such:

```
#makefile for ftconvert and calinfo
#use 'make ftconvert' to make ftconvert sample and 'make calinfo' to make calinfo
#uses gcc, needs modifications for other compilers.
object_compile = gcc -c
exe_compile = gcc -o
remove_command = rm
ftconvert: ftconvert.o ftconfig.o ftrt.o dom.o expatls.o node.o stack.o xmlparse.o xmlrole.o xmltok.o
    $(exe_compile) ftconvert.exe ftconvert.o ftconfig.o ftrt.o dom.o expatls.o node.o stack.o xmlparse.o xmlrole.o xmltok.o
ftconvert.o: ftconvert.c ../atidaq/ftconfig.h 
    $(object_compile) ftconvert.c
ftconfig.o: ../atidaq/ftconfig.c ../atidaq/ftconfig.h
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/ftconfig.c
ftrt.o: ../atidaq/ftrt.c ../atidaq/ftrt.h  ../atidaq/ftsharedrt.h
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/ftrt.c
dom.o: ../atidaq/dom.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/dom.c
expatls.o: ../atidaq/expatls.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/expatls.c
node.o: ../atidaq/node.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/node.c
stack.o: ../atidaq/stack.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/stack.c
xmlparse.o: ../atidaq/xmlparse.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/xmlparse.c
xmlrole.o: ../atidaq/xmlrole.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/xmlrole.c
xmltok.o: ../atidaq/xmltok.c
    $(object_compile) ../atidaq/xmltok.c
calinfo: calinfo.o ftconfig.o ftrt.o dom.o expatls.o node.o stack.o xmlparse.o xmlrole.o xmltok.o
    $(exe_compile) calinfo.exe calinfo.o ftconfig.o ftrt.o dom.o expatls.o node.o stack.o xmlparse.o xmlrole.o xmltok.o
calinfo.o: calinfo.c ../atidaq/ftconfig.h
    $(object_compile) calinfo.c
clean:
    $(remove_command) *.o *.exe
```

running the command: `make ftconvert` yields the error:

```
gcc -c ftconvert.c
ftconvert.c:35:32: fatal error: ..\atidaq\ftconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ftconvert.o] Error 1
```

Not sure what I am missing here or why I can't even get the stock example to work

Comment: this type of statement: ../atidaq/ftconfig.h  indicates that the directory name atidaq is lower case (all *nix OSs are case sensitive) so change the name of your main directory to (lowercase) 'atidaq'

Answer (score 0):

That's a directory name casing problem.

`atidaq` is not the same as `ATIDAQ`.

Either rename the directory or edit the makefile.

Then go complain to the people providing it that their source depends on being extracted on a platform that does not have case-sensitive file names (like Windows).

Comment: With this modification I am now onto: `make: *** No rule to make target '../ATIDAQ/ftconfig.h', needed by 'ftconvert.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: @MattStokes You edited the makefile then? Ok. What directory are you running make from?

Comment: I did edit the makefile and I am calling make from inside the Samples directory

Comment: @MattStokes Does `ls -l ../ATIDAQ/ftconfig.h` find the file correctly from that directory? Because in a quick test `s/atidaq/ATIDAQ/` on that makefile and a similar change to `ftconvert.c` (`s!\atidaq\!/ATIDAQ/`) the build worked for me... until linking when I needed to add `-lm` to the link line (after `ftconvert.exe`).